# tcolorbox inner theme - blurred background

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox

I was inspired by a talk by SamCarter and tried the following to get a blurred background effect.

I have just copied the code from her. But it doesn't seem to work.
Am I missing something?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
{\tcbset{
enhanced, remember,
frame hidden, interior hidden,
underlay={
\begin{tcbclipframe}
\begin{scope}[inner sep=0pt,
remember picture,overlay]
\fill[white] (current page.south west)
rectangle (current page.north east);
% blurred version of background image
\node[opacity=0.9] at (current page.center)
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]
{/home/vrgovinda/goloka-pictures/3-realms_2.jpg}};%
\end{scope}
\end{tcbclipframe}
}}}

\begin{block}{block title}
    Hare Krishna
\end{block}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have the relevant `beamerinnerthemetcolorbox.sty` in my `texmf` folder.

This is the result:

[image: https://imgur.com/s66Jx8p.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beamer has a very unfortunate syntax which allows `\begin{frame}`, `\begin{frame}{frametitle}` and `\begin{frame}{frametitle}{framesubtitle}`. To do this, it tests if the next character after `\begin{frame}` is a `{` and then assumes that this will be the start of the frametitle.

Compare the result of these two frames:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
{test}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

{test}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So in your specific code, the `{\tcbset...}` is being interpreted as the frametitle and the modifications never reach the block which is in the frame body and not in the title.

Replace the second `example-image-duck` with a blurred version of your background image in the code below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black}
  \setbeamerfont{block title}{series=\bfseries}
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt,remember picture,overlay]
      \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\begin{frame}

\tcbset{
  enhanced,
  remember,
  frame hidden,
  interior hidden,
  underlay={
    \begin{tcbclipframe}
      \begin{scope}[inner sep=0pt, remember picture,overlay] 
        \fill[white] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        % blurred version of background image
        \node[opacity=0.9] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}};
      \end{scope}
    \end{tcbclipframe}
  }
}

\begin{block}{block title}
    text
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What change have you made? I have also used the same code from your github page.

Comment: @vrgovinda I just added some explanations. The most important bit is to not wrap it into `{...}` and in particular not to have the `{...}` in the very first line of the frame or it will end up in the frametitle.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. So do I have to write `\begingroup ... \endgroup` for each figure that I want to have as background? Why not to just locally define them just before a frame environment using `\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}`

Comment: @vrgovinda You're welcome! Have fun with the blurred boxes!

Comment: A very nice addition to beamer indeed! Thanks a lot Sam.

Comment: The `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` is to restrict the background image to only the frames within this group. You can place one or several frames in it. If you would like to change the background for all frames, you don't need it at all.

Comment: how can I use tcolorbox inner theme to restrict the block size to text size?

Comment: @vrgovinda If you have a new question, please ask a new question

Comment: no ma'am. It is connected to this question only. If you wish I can ask separately